# Can I use jQuery pjax with backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Can I use jquery-pjax with backbone.js?

From what I can see the routing with backbone.js is done with hashes in the url, however jquery-pjax seems to do away with the need for hases for changing the state of a site/app.

Comment: from what i see pjax does not do away the hashes, it uses them for his history state, but by default push is true (you can on initialization pass push:false) due to the push state being true, it uses the new HTML5 pushState support, which does not use the hashes yes. Anyway, i'm not sure why you want to use pjax, the url changing  already works by the backbone Router, and your different pages just need to be different views, don't see any use for both at the same time...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to enable push state for Backbone to lose the hashes if supported

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});`

Edit: To clarify, neither library's will make push state work in older browsers that doesn't support it, they use fallback behaviours. There are two ways to support older browsers, either you use hashes as Backbone does and this provides a more consistent experience. With pjax you will have to hard load the url which is not ideal within the Backbone paradigm, resulting in having to build multiple separate pages for every possible route your backbone app would have.

Comment: won't that just only work in certain browsers? in others he still will have the conflicts between backbone's router's hashes and the pjax's hashes?

Comment: I can't see pjax doing any different.

Comment: Are you sure? That's not a very reassuring answer.

Comment: I'm sure that older browsers don't support push state and pjax can't magically make them use it that any more than backbone can.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer technically pjax does magically handle browsers that don't support push state because it fallbacks to just reloading the entire page (not ideal, but everything still works).

Comment: @JakeHoffner My mistake about the behaviour but that's even a worse option when working within the Backbone paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can. Here is a [head start](https://github.com/jeromegn/backbone.pjax).

Different question is if it makes sense. What I mean is that by design Backbone

> connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface

Oversimplifying it but the usual steps are:

1. Create Model
2. [Fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) an API that will retrieve JSON data
3. Pass model to the view
4. Render the view with a template
5. Append the html generated by the view into the DOM

With PJAX you can skip all that since you will have the html from the PJAX response.